# how to show all image urls along with username, title, uid,timestamp in adapter class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to show all image URLs along with username, timestamp, and title but only one image is showing. I'm using recyclerview adapter. I want to show all image URLs with a long title, timestamp, and username in adapter like one post

[image]

This is how I'm storing in firebase database using  blog class

```
 ArrayList<Uri> arrayListImageDownloadUri = new ArrayList<>();
                            final Uri downloaduri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                            Log.v("DOWNLOAD URI", String.valueOf(downloaduri));
                            blogimages.add(downloaduri.toString());
                            Log.v("BLOGGIMAGES", String.valueOf(blogimages));
                           // final String path=  uri.getLastPathSegment();
                            final DatabaseReference ref =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("posts/");


                            final String newPostKey = ref.push().getKey();
                            final String posttitle = desc.getText().toString();
                            final String CurrentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            userid = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog").child(CurrentUser).push();
                            ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                            for(int i=0; i<blogimages.size();i++) {

                                arrayList.add( blogimages.get(i).toString());
                                Log.v("IMAGESADDING PHSE3", String.valueOf(arrayList));
                            }
                            Log.v("COCOCOCOCO", String.valueOf(arrayList));

                                n.put(String.valueOf("img"), blogimages.get(i).toString());*/
                                Blog blog = new Blog();
                                long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                int timestamp = ((int) (millis/1000))* -1;
                                blog.setTitle(posttitle);
                                blog.setUrl(arrayList);
                                blog.setUid(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());


                            mdatabaseReference.child(CurrentUser).setValue(blog)

                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        Intent mm = new Intent(PhotoUploadActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(mm);
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(PhotoUploadActivity.this, "Failed to post the blog.. Try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this in on success listener when you get blog data:

```
 rootRef.child("Blog").child("blogId").child(url).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                urlList.add(dataSnapshot.getValue()); //you will receive single element 
    //every time in this listener you can store it in list then you can give it to your adapter out side this listener
                }
            ...
```

***NOTE:*** you must implement method on Child Changed,Removed...

Comment: No this is how i'm sending to adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,list,firebaseAuth,mdatabaseReference,likesdatabaseReference);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
mchildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
String j = dataSnapshot.getKey();
Blog friendlyMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(Blog.class);
friendlyMessage.setPostkey(j);
list.add(friendlyMessage);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}};mquery.addChildEventListener(mchildEventListener);

Comment: make new constructeur for Blog class and pass to it url list

Comment: I didn't got it . This is my getter and setter for image urls in blog class.   public ArrayList<String> getUrl()
    {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(ArrayList<String> url)
    {
        this.url = url;
    }

Comment: after this line ` Blog friendlyMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(Blog.class);` use my code then friendlyMessage.setUrl(urlList);

Comment: i don't want only image urls and i also need  username, timestamp and title with these list of image urls , shown to adapete. In our answer urlList is arraylist<String> or arraylist<Blog>. I want to show all images with one username and title like facebook posts

Comment: yes you are firstly received all information in this statment and next you received urls in my answer then you set the urls into your object in this statment friendlyMessage.setUrl(urlList); then you will add this object to the list in this statment list.add(friendlyMessage); that's it :) .

Comment: What is urlList its arraylist<String> or arraylist<Blog>